# IPN of recurring payments in Paypal have any different parameters than the normal invoice payment?

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm developing a IPN listener wich must be able to catch recurring payments, invoice payments and subscriptions payments. I already reviewed to much documentation about this topic. 
I hope someone can tell me the main differences between the POST that paypal sends to my listener on when the txn_type variable when it changes their value to:

- txn_type=invoice_payment
- txn_type=recurring_payment
- txn_type=subscr_payment

I already has made a transaction with txn_type=invoice_payment, here is the IPN resend:

```
invoice_number=0003
invoice_id=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
mc_gross_1=58.00
mc_handling1=0.00
num_cart_items=1
payer_id=DJ77XLF8321SCCQ
address_country_code=
ipn_track_id=901559bfkk956f2d
address_zip=6546
invoice=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
charset=windows-1252
payment_gross=
address_status=unconfirmed
address_street=
verify_sign=AFcWxVudFQq8ZSboMdT0X3W4ahu5PTNt
tax1=0.00
txn_type=invoice_payment
receiver_id=5VPNPEENCQ
payment_fee=
item_number1=
mc_currency=
transaction_subject=
custom=
protection_eligibility=Eligible
quantity1=1
address_country=
payer_status=verified
first_name=
item_name1=Pago+0003
address_name=
mc_gross=58.00
mc_shipping1=0.00
payment_date=10%3a24%3a19+Mar+08%2c+2016+PST
payment_status=Completed
business=
last_name=
address_state=
txn_id=9GE9035442720
mc_fee=7.30
resend=true
payment_type=instant
notify_version=3.8
payer_email=
receiver_email=
address_city=
residence_country=
```

I'm mainly interested on know if the variable invoice_id= appears on the recurring and subscription payments.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For recurring payments if you passed an invoice ID in the PROFILEREFERENCE parameter of the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile request it would come back as rp_invoice_id in the IPN.

For subscriptions it would come back as "invoice" if included in the request.

To make the API calls you can send an HTTP request as an NVP string or you can use SOAP.

- [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile NVP Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile SOAP Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_SOAP/)

Comment: Thanks Andrew but this is not useful for me, I'm working on C# with paypal api, there is not a createRecurringPaymentsProfile method. I'm working like that: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/BillingPlanCreate.aspx.cs. Regards!

Comment: I haven't looked at the SDK you reference, but the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API can be used from any language.  Just make the HTTP calls yourself.  You don't need the SDK.  I've updated the answer with links the API reference.

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrew Angell, but I already figure it out in c# without any profile creation, when I create a new "Plan" (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/payments.billing-plans/#plan.create) and the "Agreement" (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest/api/payments.billing-agreements/) using paypal SDK, paypal API return to me a token from the plan and agreement ID  from the agreement that will be useful for my purpose.